# 1300 2500 pronunciation

Tags: numbers

A BrE speaker told me that 1300 BC is pronounced as "thirteen hundred bee cee" but saying 2500 BC/AD/CE as twenty-five hundred  bee cee or AD/CE or is uncommon. Why is it so?

If it depends on each native speaker's personal preference then is it true that 2500BC/CE/AD can be pronounced in the following different ways below?

"two thousand five hundred BC/CE/AD" or "twenty-five hundred BC/AD/CE",
or without "BC/AD/CE " twenty-five hundred" and "two thousand five hundred".

Comment: As an American, I find that a very strange remark. In most circumstances, I would say *twenty-five hundred BC/AD/CE*. I would say *two thousand five hundred* only if I wanted to draw special attention to the date—to emphasize how very near or far away it was.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney  I'm also an American, and I don't find saying "two thousand five hundred BC" to be that unusual.

Comment: @stangdon I meant only that the claim about "twenty-five hundred" was strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating what OP probably already knows: Traditionally, years after and including the year [AD] 1 are considered AD (Anno Domini), and years before this are considered BC (Before Christ), counting backwards from 1 BC. I've discovered when double checking my answer that there was apparently no year AD 0. I've also discovered that some people write AD before the number (which I'm doing here, but I normally put it after the number myself). These terms come from old Christian traditions. There's a secular version of the same system called BCE (Before Common Era) and CE (Common Era) which is sometimes used instead.

Now to answer this:

> ...is it true that 2500BC/CE/AD can be pronounced in the following different ways below?
> "two thousand five hundred BC/CE/AD" or "twenty-five hundred BC/AD/CE", or without "BC/AD/CE " twenty-five hundred" and "two thousand five hundred".

If you write or say the name of a year without specifying whether it's BC or AD, people will automatically interpret it as AD. That's not a personal preference. As far as I'm aware, that's how everyone does it. So it's fine to say 2500 instead of AD 2500.

But 2500 BC/BCE is always said with BC/BCE. So that doesn't work for you last 2 examples. You can't refer to 2500 BC as just "two thousand five hundred" because people expect that to mean AD 2500. We might be able to figure it out if we already know what you mean, but it sounds odd and could be confusing.

Comment: do I understand correctly if I mean AD or CE I don't need to pronounce  them   and I can say two thousand five hundred or twenty-five hundred with or without ei dee  or see ee. But if I mean bee cee then it should be pronounced and it is said as twenty-five hundred bee cee or two thousand five hundred bee cee. Omitted bee cee is wrong.

Comment: @AntoniaA Yes. It's normal to omit AD/CE, but it's important not to omit BC/BCE.

Answer (score 4):

This is a personal preference. As far as I'm aware as a native (British) speaker there is no fixed requirement or convention for how these are spoken. Either when talking specifically about years, or just using the numbers for counting of things such as "two thousand five hundred people attended the rally".

My personal guidance in this area would come from they way the spoken numbers change style when going above twenty. Numbers above twenty are broken into the "ten" and "digit" part sequentially, below twenty they are either single words (0 to 12) or a single word that signifies the digit before the ten (13-19) "fifteen" (five-ten).

Under 2000 I'd use the xxx-hundred style. Above 2000 I'd shift to using the x-thousand-y-hundred notation.

Additionally, the most common convention for year AD around the current period, i.e. 2021 is to split into two numbers "Twenty Twenty-One", this has been the most common format since 2010, smaller than that would have been "Two thousand and X" because "Twenty - Nine" is highly ambigous.

Comment: It's definitely personal preference. I'm a native British person I read those numbers in my head as "thirteen hundred" and "twenty five hundred," contrary to OP's friend's preference.